# cannot see log items for connected ipad in console

Tags: ipad, console

I have attached an iPad to my MacBook and I made the iPad trust the MacBook.

I've opened up the Console application where I can see both my MacBook and the iPad, but I am only seeing messages come through for my MacBook - the iPad has a little triangle containing an exclamation mark next to it and an empty message log. I can't see anything in the UI to indicate what the problem is or how to diagnose it.

How can I get message logging working for the iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And it turns out that clicking on the triangle containing the exclamation mark was the required step to make log messages start flowing.